# How to cleanup object of StackFrame class in vb. Net??

Tags: vb.net

Can someone let me know how to cleanup object of StackFrame class in vb. Net.. Is there any existing method for it which performs the cleanup of the object or we need to manually implement a method for cleaning up the object. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by `performs the cleanup of the object`? It's not disposable so by setting its reference to `Nothing` should be enough.

Comment: If it's not disposable, don't even set it to nothing. Setting variables to Nothing is an anachronistic holdover from the vb6 era. Just let it go out of scope.

Comment: It is the job of the garbage collector to clean it up.  Trying to help is a mistake, beyond it not being possible.